# Javascript function for select menu not working as intended to in some browsers

Tags: javascript

I' trying to write function that will fill spaces provided with elements from predefined arrays when I select them from dropdown menu. Code here only works in firefox, but not in other browsers(IE or Chrome - I tested with them). A don't know what is wrong with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zadatak2.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var milos=["Milos","Teodosić","Olimpijakos","1987","196cm","20.6","6","8","plejmejker"];
            var nenad=["Nenad","Krstić","Oklahoma","1983","212cm","20.4","13.5","8","centar"];
            var marko=["Marko","Kešelj","Olimpijakos","1988","207cm","11.1","3","1","krilo"];

            function set(a) {
                for (i=0, o=1; i<8; i++, o++) {
                    document.getElementById('b'+o).value=a[i];
                }

                document.getElementById('plejmejker').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('centar').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('bek').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('krilo').checked = false;
                document.getElementById(a[8]).checked = true;
            }
        </script>       

        <title>Zadatak</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="titles">
            <img class="logo" src="slike\kss_logo.png"/>
            <h1>Košarkaška reprezentacija Srbije</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="side">
            <h3>Reprezentacije</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Grupa A
                    <ul>
                        <li>Srbija</li>
                        <li>Argentina</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Grupa B
                    <ul>
                        <li>SAD</li>
                        <li>Slovenija</li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    Grupa C
                    <ul>
                        <li>Turska</li>
                        <li>Grčka</li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    Grupa D
                    <ul>
                        <li>Litvanija</li>
                        <li>Španija</li>
                        <li>Francuska</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>

            <img class="logo" src="slike\bbcup_logo.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="kosarkas">
                    <label>Odaberite košarkaša: </label>
                    <select id="player">
                        <option value="milos" onmousedown="set(milos)">Miloš Teodosić</option>
                        <option value="nenad" onmousedown="set(nenad)">Nenad Krstić</option>
                        <option value="marko" onmousedown="set(marko)">Marko Kešelj</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>Podaci o košarkašu:</h2>
                </div>

                <div id="formleft">
                    <label class="label">Ime:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b1"/><br />

                    <label class="label">Rođen:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b4"/><br />

                    <label class="label">Visina:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b5"/><br />

                    <label class="label">Skokova:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b7"/><br />
                </div>

                <div id="formright">
                    <label class="label">Prezime:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b2"/><br />

                    <label class="label">Klub:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b3"/><br />

                    <label class="label" style="margin-top:-5%">pozicija:</label>
                    <div id="dropdown">
                        <input type="radio" id="plejmejker"/>plejmejker<br />
                        <input type="radio" id="bek"/>bek<br />
                        <input type="radio" id="krilo"/>krilo<br />
                        <input type="radio" id="centar"/>centar<br/>
                    </div>

                    <label class="label">Asistencija:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="b8"/><br />
                </div>

                <div class="kosarkas">
                    <label class="label">Prosek poena: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="b6"/><br />
                </div>
            </form>
            <p id="footer">Svjetsko prvenstvo u košarci, septembar 2014</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the `onmousedown` event - I don't think it reliably fires for `option` elements across all browsers.  Try changing your `select` to:

```
<select id="player" onchange="set(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="milos">Miloš Teodosić</option>
    <option value="nenad">Nenad Krstić</option>
    <option value="marko">Marko Kešelj</option>
</select>
```

You'll also need to change your `set` function slightly, since it's currently expecting the object to be passed in, not a string value:

```
function set(player) {
    var a;
    switch(player) {
        case 'milos':
            a = milos;
            break;
        case 'nenad':
            a = nenad;
            break;
        case 'marko':
            a = marko;
            break;
    }
    for (i=0, o=1; i<8; i++, o++) {
        document.getElementById('b'+o).value=a[i];
    }

    document.getElementById('plejmejker').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('centar').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('bek').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('krilo').checked = false;
    document.getElementById(a[8]).checked = true;
}
```